# spring-mvc form validation

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have program with form vaidation in spring-mvc.

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.evgeny.spring.form.beans.Person;

@Controller
public class FormController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,value="some")
    public ModelAndView goRegistrate(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("person", new Person());
        mav.setViewName("regForm");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value="reg")
    public ModelAndView handleForm(@Valid Person person){
        person.setId(person.getId()+1);
        person.setName(person.getName()+"test");
        return new ModelAndView("view","personPlus",person);
    }
}
```

Person bean:

```
public class Person {
    @Size(max=100, min=0,message="0 to 100")
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person() {
        this.id = 1;
        this.name = "No name";

    }

    //Getters and Setters...
}
```

the form:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sf:form method="post" modelAttribute="person" action="reg.htm">
        <sf:input path="id" id="personId"/>
        <sf:input path="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The validation don't work. When i enter value out of the bound 0 to 100 the program continues.

I don't have  in my spring config file. when i add it i got:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Could not create Configuration.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you defined validator bean?

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

You may need to add `validation` dependency as well..

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.validation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
```